# Listen for animation end on the Android Gallery control

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a standard Android Gallery control:

```
<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/galArt"
    android:spacing="10dp"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
    android:unselectedAlpha="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

From which I listen to events with this code:

```
galArt.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            showMessageToast("Selected: " + pos);           
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    });
```

This works as I guess it is intended to: when I swipe the image, I get a toast telling me which image is now selected.

However, this toast appears *before* the image has stopped sliding, while the animation is still running. I want to take action *after* it has stopped sliding, to avoid interrupting the animation.

What can I listen to in order to get the notification after the animation is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have found a solution. Note that this is merely *a* solution, and not necessarily the *best* solution.

My solution is to just ignore all the logical events (like onScroll or onAnimationEnd, since I couldn't get any of them to work anyway), and listen to changes in a child view's location. When the child view is stationary, the animation has ended.

An actual benefit of doing it this way is that this works for both dragging and flinging.

A problem is that the onItemSelected function will be called from another thread than your UI thread. Solve that by using your activity's runOnUIThread function, as shown in the example.

The way to listen for changes (note that this is not the regular **onItemSelected** function, but rather my own **onItemReallySelected**):

```
galArt.setOnItemReallySelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Do your stuff here ...
                }
            });
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        //... or here.
    }
});
```

My implementation of the Android Gallery:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Gallery;

public class ArtGallery extends Gallery {

    OnItemSelectedListener _listener;
    Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public ArtGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ArtGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ArtGallery(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            setTimer();
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private int _lastScrollX = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private void setTimer() {
        //Cancel existing tasks (if any), and create a new timer.
        _timer.cancel();
        _timer = new Timer();

        //Schedule our animation check.
        _timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Just some value that will change while the animation is running.
                int x = getSelectedView().getLeft(); 
                if(_lastScrollX != x){
                    //Value has changed; save current value, and reset the timer.
                    _lastScrollX = x;
                    setTimer();
                }else{
                    //The value hasn't changed during the last 50ms. That probably means that the animation has stopped.
                    fireOnSelected();
                }
            }
        }, 50); 
    }

    public void setOnItemReallySelectedListener(OnItemSelectedListener listener){
        _listener = listener;
    }

    //This function is copied from the Android Gallery source code, and works exactly like the original one.
    private void fireOnSelected() {
        if (_listener == null)
            return;

        int selection = this.getSelectedItemPosition();
        if (selection >= 0) {
            _listener.onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), selection, getAdapter().getItemId(selection));
        } else {
            _listener.onNothingSelected(this);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hy Erlend, i tried your solution and it works. The only problem is that it doesnt fire on the first item, when you start the Gallery.
Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: No, I never needed it to fire on the initialization of the gallery. I would suggest that you either simply call yourFunction() manually after setting it up for the first time. Or perhaps you could override setAdapter or something like that in the ArtGallery class, and then call fireOnSelected from there.